# Regular expression to validate name in .NET multilingual web application

Tags: c#, .net, multilingual

how can i write a regular expression to validate name field in a multilingual web application, i want to validate the name field for non-English languages e.g. Spanish or German, and we need to make sure that no one enter digits or special characters. I'm using .NET 2.0

I believe we can't use expression as below for non-English language.

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,20}$
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

I got this Regular Expression, it works fien when i uses [Regex Builder](http://renschler.net/RegexBuilder/) but when i try it in actual web application it fails:

```
^\p{L}[\p{L}\p{Pd}\x27]*\p{L}$
```

Comment: What's wrong? Ç being matched?

Comment: Short Answer: Don't. There is someone on the planet with the moniker "Number 16 Bus Shelter" and you will be blocking them from your site! Source: http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/7522952.stm. So you would be imposing a somwhat arbitrary restriction on the domain which does not match the actual restrictions in the real world. Why do you need to validate this anyway?

Comment: @Martin: That's very insightful! Thanks for sharing the link, i have been against this, but now i have a reference :D

Comment: Pointless validation like this just adds more code and that's code you have to test. What's going to break if someone has a number in their name? Richard the 3rd?

Comment: Use ^[A-Za-z]{0,7}$ , as there's more than enough combinations of matches than people in the world at this time.  Plus, it works on my first name and my last name.

Comment: @Joey: The Expression won't work for multilingual applications.

Answer (score 5):

use `\w` for letter. it is multilingual friendly

Comment: Will it only allow only alphabets with spaces, and no digits and special chracters???

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x(VS.85).aspx the \w is equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_], for J(ava)Script - which is used client-side by a regexvalidator.

Comment: see the header "JScript
Regular Expression Syntax (Scripting)". it is not .net, it is jscript

Comment: @Andery, so it means it include digit as well, beucase it has Nd this as well: {Nd - Number, Decimal Digit}

Comment: yes, it includes them. If you want ONLY letters then specify explicitly using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#CategoryOrBlock

Comment: ^\p{L}[\p{L}\p{Pd}\x27]*\p{L}$ i got this regular expression, it works fine when i test it using RegEx Builder, but it fails when i actually put it in ASP.NET page.

Comment: @Andrey: infact i'm changing the UI culture and current culture to the language user selects, is it the reason? what should i do??