# .NET String Encoding - Character Converting

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, character-encoding

I have a string variable that stores a text in Turkish language

```
string str = "açğş";
```

I want to convert each character of this string to appropriate English Letter.

So that the conversion must be like: , açğş --> acgs

How can I do it using .NET/C# ?

Comment: Maybe this will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621275/regular-expression-to-validate-name-in-net-multilingual-web-application

Comment: I personally like the one that [StackOverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/non-us-ascii-characters-dropped-from-full-profile-url/7696#7696) uses to convert characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From one of Jeff Atwood's [original posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-do-you-include-a-webpage-title-as-part-of-a-webpage-url/25486#25486) on URL purifying, they call [RemapInternationalCharToAscii](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/non-us-ascii-characters-dropped-from-full-profile-url/7696#7696). please check that/those post(s) out, as I believe they are a great solution (and, given it's [Jeff Atwood ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) speed has been taken in to consideration).

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] notAccpetedA = new string[] {"ã","ä"};
string mystring = "ãçğş";
foreach(string _char in notAcceptedA)
{
mystring.Replace(_char,"a");
}
```

Comment: this is only a sample and will need to be expanded on

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:
str = str.Replace("ç", "c").Replace("ğ", "g").Replace("Ç", "C")....;

Answer (score 0):

1- use `Dictionary<char,string> Dic= new Dictionary<char,string>();`

2- populate the dictionary with Translation letters

3-  `strOut =String.Join("", StrIn.ToCharArray().Select(C=>Dic.ContainsKey(C)?Dic[C]:C.ToString()).ToArray());`