# Regex for German and Chinese characters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, diacritics

I have to validate the German & Chinese characters in the given input box. How can I check the regular expression for German and Chinese characters in javascript? What regex could I use to achieve this?

Please give me an example.

Comment: This is a repeated question with an answer over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621275/regular-expression-to-validate-name-in-net-multilingual-web-application

Comment: @mangobug Your link is a .net question and that answer will not work for JavaScript, because regex in JavaScript has NO Unicode support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lib from [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) and a according [XRegExp Unicode plugins](http://xregexp.com/plugins/) that extends the javasript regex features. That adds support for Unicode categories, scripts, and blocks.

See [regular-expressions.info/unicode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) for more informations about Unicode categories, scripts, and blocks.

The German special characters should be in the Unicode block `\p{InLatin-1_Supplement}`, for the Chinese alphabet you have to check which script or block is correct.

If you want to accept any character that is a letter, in any alphabet represented in Unicode, then you can use `\p{L}`.

See [XRegExp Unicode plugins](http://xregexp.com/plugins/) for examples on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario it's probably easier to specify the characters which are allowed, and see if there are any others, like this:

```
var myString = "üöäÜÖÄß";
if (!/[a-z0-9]/gi.test(myString))
    alert('Non English-Alpha characters in: ' + myString)
```

Comment: i have to check Chinese & German & some other languages. so this is not a good idea to add in this string each chars. Is there any other solution.